# How to overwrite image and link path in iframe object?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I try to create an iframe and replace images and links source with my own sources to remove disturbing contents like pornography, violence etc. Removing is not allowed by iframe. I use sandbox for prevent scripts and flash. Is there a way for this? Or what is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch website content by ajax, then replace all occurrences that you looking for and display data. I am quite not sure whether it will be possible to insert dom directly into iframe or object. I will check that out.

If that fails, you can create intermediate service, for instance in PHP, to grab content by curl and then display script results in iframe on your own server.